# How to have active and loaded scene in Unity but not render it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make simple multiplayer game (2d shooter) in Unity and I want to have two projects. One for client and one for server. I looked for some existing tools for making servers from games (to inspire myself) like Argo and Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 and they have one thing in common. It's only command prompt. And I like that idea and I had similar idea of look of the tool I am trying to make now.

Before any programming I thought about how the things will work. And I devised that when player shoot, his client will send position of player's gun, direction, etc. And after that the server would send to all client which directions is the bullet flying, etc. And I want to server handle bullet collisions. So...

... the scene in the server project has to be loaded, active and etc. But I'd like to show only the command prompt.

I heard about async in Unity but I am not sure if the scene would be fully active before async.allowSceneActivation = true or if is there any better way to do this in Unity.

I hope you understand my problem and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [SpatialOS](https://improbable.io/spatialos) -- it's a framework & service where they run Unity in the cloud to handle calculations. It's not super-easy to use though, and last time I checked requires custom solutions for voice chat.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why don't you use PUN or Photon? It would be the simplest way. If you want to code it yourself, I think launching a Unity scene on your server would be a bad approach. Take a look at server-side scripting languages.

To run a Unity game in headless-mode you have to make a little script:

```html
using UnityEditor;
class MyScript
{
     static void PerformBuild ()
     {
         string[] scenes = { "Assets/MyScene.unity" };
         BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, ...);
     }
}
```

and then start the game over command line like `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -nographics -projectPath "c:\myproj"`

If you want it for Linux: `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -nographics -projectPath "c:\myproj" -buildLinuxUniversalPlayer "c:\myprojbin"`

Comment: I don't use Photon or Unity's HLAPI because I want to learn more how multiplayer works. And I don't know what you mean by 'server-side scripting languages'. I wront int the topic that the server needs to run the actual scene because it'll handle the bullet collision.